# I send 7 messages throw GCM and receive respond for 35 messages

Tags: java, http, google-cloud-messaging, multicast

I am using Gcm multicast messaging over http, I provide any number of Ids, and send the message...
my first multicast contains 35 IDs (35 target users)...
**the second and third and go on multicasts contain just 7 Ids but I still  receive respond for 35 messages (instead of the 7)**

> code for send over http:

```
  try{
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new         URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send").openConnection();

 connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=AIzaSyASH05wdoY42OkmCvGwEbkihKzcwRCfDnQ");

// Write to the connection
  OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
output.write(content.getBytes(charset));// content is a Json message with 7 IDs in the field (registration_ids:"xxxxx","xxxx",....)
output.close();

InputStream inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
if (inputStream == null)
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

// Read everything from our stream
BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new       InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));

String inputLine;


while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
responseReader.close();
}catch(IOException io)
{
System.err.println("Error3 "+io);
}
return response.toString();
}
   try{
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(http_url_old).openConnection();

 connection.setDoOutput(true);
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
 connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",     "key=AIzaSyASH05wdoY42OkmCvGwEbkihKzcwRCfDnQ");

// Write to the connection

OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
output.write(content.getBytes(charset));
output.close();

// Check the error stream first, if this is null then there have been no issues with the request
InputStream inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
if (inputStream == null)
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

// Read everything from our stream
BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, charset));

String inputLine;


while ((inputLine = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
responseReader.close();
}catch(IOException io)
{
 System.err.println("Error3 "+io);
}
 return response.toString();
}
```

but When I receive A respond the server respond like this:

> {"multicast_id":6414471465709567733,"success":28,"failure":7,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_....ect

28+7 = 35, I just send 7 messages!!!
respond (for 35) after I sent many times Just multicast that contains just 7 Ids!

how to get the correct respond?

Answer (score 1):

is seem to be mu fault:

```
response.append(inputLine);
```

I append the new result so the "response" String keep growing

the solution: reset the String every time I send new multicast..